# Refresh Ember.CollectionView on contentBinding reordering

Tags: ember.js

I have an `VenuesView` bound to `VenuesController` through contentBinding.

```
window.VenuesView = Em.CollectionView.extend
  contentBinding: 'VenuesController'
  itemViewClass: VenueView

window.VenuesController = Em.SortableController.create
  content: [10, 11, 3, 101, 500, 2]
```

For some reason sorting / reordering `VenuesController.content` doesn't update the page, but any other operation on it does.

```
# Doesn't update DOM
VenuesController.set('content', VenuesController.get('content').sort())

# Updates DOM, but clears table and messes up users scroll position.
c = VenuesController.get('content').sort()
VenuesController.set('content', [])
VenuesController.set('content', c)
```

Does anyone know how to re-render the view after reordering content without emptying and repopulating the array?

Answer (score 2):

If you modify a property manually you want to use `this.propertyWillChange('content')` and `propertyDidChange('content')` before and after the sorting.

```js
App.Sortable = Ember.Mixin.create({
    sort: function() {
        this.propertyWillChange('content');
        this.get('content').sort( App.sort );
        this.propertyDidChange('content');
    }
});

App.venuesController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create(App.Sortable, {
    content: [10, 11, 3, 101, 500, 2]
});
```

---

I propose another way: create a computed property `sorted` which returns a sorted array and is automatically updated when the item's change or values are added or removed, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/qqHf6/:

```js
App.Sorted = Ember.Mixin.create({
    sorted: function() {
        return this.get('content').sort(App.sort);
    }.property('@each')
});

App.venuesController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create(App.Sorted, {
    content: [10, 11, 3, 101, 500, 2]
});
```

---

Also have a look at the blog post about Ember.js naming conventions: http://www.emberist.com/2012/04/09/naming-conventions.html . So instances like your controller are lowerCase and classes like your view are UpperCase.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling `contentWillChange` and only then calling `contentDidChange` on your controller?